# activeMQ does not participate in Weblogic XA transactions

Tags: jms, weblogic, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I try to get XA transactions involving a jdbc and jms DataSource working in a Spring webapp deployed to Weblogic.

Using a local Atomikos TransactionManager, this works - I see XA debug messages in ActiveMQ, and stuff stays consistent. In Weblogic however, the database and ActiveMQ are not transactionally consistent.

I have added a foreign JMS server in Weblogic

JNDI Initial Context Factory:

```
org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
```

JNDI Connection URL:

```
tcp://localhost:61616
```

JNDI Properties:

```
connectionFactoryNames=XAConnectionFactory
```

To that server, I have added a ConnectionFactory (Remote JNDI Name = XAConnectionFactory). Lookups work, so far so good.

In my code, this is how I setup the Spring JTA:

```
@Override
   @Bean
   @Profile(AppConfig.PROFILE_WEBLOGIC)
   public JtaTransactionManager transactionManager()
   {
      WebLogicJtaTransactionManager tx = new WebLogicJtaTransactionManager();
      tx.afterPropertiesSet();

      return tx;
   }
```

And this is my JMS config:

```
   @Bean
   @Profile(AppConfig.PROFILE_WEBLOGIC)
   public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
   {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, env.getProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY));
      props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, env.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL));

      try
      {
         InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
         ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory) ctx
            .lookup(env.getProperty("jms.connectionFactory"));

         return connectionFactory;
      }
      catch(NamingException e)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("XAConnectionFactory lookup failed", e);
      }
   }

   @Bean
   public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException
   {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      factory.setTransactionManager(txConfig.transactionManager());
      factory.setBackOff(new FixedBackOff());

      return factory;
   }

   @Bean(name = "jmsTemplate")
   @Override
   public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException
   {
      JmsTemplate t = new JmsTemplate();
      t.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      t.setMessageTimestampEnabled(true);
      t.setMessageIdEnabled(true);

      return t;
   }
```

My JMS consumer is annotated with:

```
@Transactional   
@JmsListener(destination = "test.q1")
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this only works via the Resource Adapter, its not possible solely via the JNDI ConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, using the undocumented ActiveMQ JNDI property "xa=true" in the foreign JMS server definition, see here:

- [Deployment of ActiveMQ resource adapter fails](https://community.oracle.com/message/13729576#13729576)
- [ActiveMQInitialConnectionFactory cannot return an
  XAConnectionFactory](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/jira-Created-AMQ-2656-ActiveMQInitialConnectionFactory-cannot-return-an-XAConnectionFactory-tt2371871.html)
- [ActiveMQInitialConnectionFactory returns XA
  connection factory](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQInitialConnectionFactory-returns-XA-connection-factory-tt4709140.html)